# How to read a .xls file using J2ME

Tags: apache, java-me, symbian, apache-poi

i am developing a mobile application for Symbian S40 platform and i am using J2ME.so i just want to read a .xls file.

so please tell me how can i do this?

can i use [Apache POI](http://poi.apache.org/) for this purpose?

Answer (score 4):

The two primary ways of reading Excel files with Java are POI and [JExcelApi](http://jexcelapi.sourceforge.net/). However, both are written for Java SE and use classes not found in the CLDC-based Java ME implementations such as Nokia phones.

These projects are open source, so you can always try to extract the code you need from them and/or port them to the more restricted CLDC/MIDP platform.

Alternatively, is there a way you can push the reading of the spreadsheets to the server instead? Have a servlet/JSP use POI/JExcelApi to parse the spreadsheet and return the information you need in a format your client application can parse.